# "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool" error while installing android studio

Tags: release-freya, android, ide, android-studio

I have tried to install Android Studio and my Android Studio setup says this :

> "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool".

`uname -a`

```
x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue from the fix suggested for "[Issue 82711](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82711)" by installing the following  32-bit binaries

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

From [set up Android Studio on Linux](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio)

> Note: You may also need to install the ia32-libs, lib32ncurses5-dev, and lib32stdc++6 packages. These packages are required to support 32-bit apps on a 64-bit machine.

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs lib32ncurses5-dev lib32stdc++6
```